# Showing app download page Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

In my iOS app, I have used the Firebase dynamic links to share some of the contents with others. It's simply a custom domain URL with the content ID appended. With this Firebase dynamic URL's, I have successfully implemented to do this task-"When user tap and opens in the mobile phone if the app installed in the phone it will open directly from the app with relevant contents"

But I want to do the following tasks :

1. If the app has not installed in the mobile, and if the user opens the URL then show a small web page in the default web browser with the app download link which user can click and download which will direct the user to the app store app. This needs to only happen on the mobile.
2. We have a web app for the mobile app so in case if the user opens the URL shared in the Desktop or Laptop I need them to redirect to the relevant content web page.

Hope kind support on this... Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can do these settings when creating a new dynamic link:

[image]

Just make sure you "Skip the app preview page" is not selected, this way the user will have a web page with a download button to take them to the app store.

[image]

Comment: I think this is an old screenshot. When I create a dynamic link the entire user interface is different ....

Comment: Not sure why the downvote? This is the latest Firebase DynamicLink dashboard which I'm using at the moment.  For the user interface if you don't skip the preview page you'll have the default dynamic link page preview with your values, otherwise you'll have your own custom url page.

Comment: This is now what I want... I want to host a small page which I need to show a custom web page to download the app.